# WCF Security - protecting passed parameters

Tags: wcf, https, wcf-security

I have several WCF services that each except several parameters. The service uses transport security over https. If fiddler is sniffing on the computer it can see all parameters sent to the service. Is there a way to protect the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a way: you will not trust Fiddler certificate.

Fiddler works like HTTPS proxy so your client is not connecting with HTTPS to the service but to the Fiddler and Fiddler makes a new HTTPS connection to the service. Because of that Fiddler has all content decrypted.

To allow this scenario your service must trust Fiddler certificate (self-signed) because otherwise your service would refuse the connection to the Fiddler. Once you allowed [Fiddler to install its certificate](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp) to your certification store it can capture and decrypt messages.